# What is the down-stand beam called at an edge of a surface bed or raft foundation?

Tags: structural-engineering, foundations

What is the down-stand beam called at an edge of a surface bed or raft foundation? It is not exactly a grade beam or stem wall. It is more like a toe.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the down stand beam called at an edge of a surface bed or raft foundation? It is not exactly a grade beam or stem wall. It is more like a toe.

This is probably a regional nomenclature thing, since I'm seeing quite a few ways for naming this.  If you call it a grade beam, I don't think anyone will take it amiss.

Examples below of different ways of naming it.

---

**Grade Beam**

[image: grade beam]
<sup>([source](http://makatimidrisecondo.weebly.com/mat-foundations.html))</sup>

---

**Exterior Beam**

[image: exterior beam]
<sup>([source](http://www.jwkhomeinspections.com/blog/joe-keresztury-san-antonio-home-inspector-new-home-slab-foundation.html))</sup>

---

**Stem Wall or Thickened-Edge Slab**

[image: stem wall]
<sup>([source)](https://www.nachi.org/structural-design-foundations-home-inspector.htm)</sup>

---

**Beam Strip**

[image]
<sup>([source](http://www.abuildersengineer.com/2013_01_01_archive.html))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is an "edge beam", or "grade beam", in a raft foundation, and a "downturn" of a slab-on-grade. The former is a structural component, usually spanning between columns, thus more massive and heavily reinforced. The latter is a strip footing or purposed to stiffen the slab edge and prevent outward migration of the subgrade.

[image]